# \selectlanguage in the middle of text causes extra vertical space

Tags: babel, amsthm, white-space

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}

Some text

\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\selectlanguage{french}%
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}

Some text

\end{document}
```

which resulted in:

[image]

As one can see, the use of `\selectlanguage{French}` in the middle of two `proof` environments causes some extra whitespace. I think this is probably because some missing `%` in the definition of `\selectlanguage`, but how can I fix this on my side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not triggered by spurious spaces--if you use `\selectlanguage` between words you can see that it is doesn't produce a space--, the problem is that `\selectlanguage` contains  \write commands, this is a whatsits and change spacing. You would get a similar effect e.g. with `\addcontentsline`.

hyperref which creates lots of whatsits too has some code to save and restore spacing, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578793/2388 and https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/114.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}

Some text

\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
%
\makeatletter
\Hy@SaveLastskip
\selectlanguage{french}%
\Hy@RestoreLastskip
\makeatother
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

[image]