# Add text color to "proof" environment without adding extra vertical space

Tags: color, amsthm, hooks

Consider the following MWE, in which I'm trying to change the text color of the environment `proof` via the hook `env/proof/begin`. However, the use of `\color` would give extra vertical space when following a theorem type environment. Is there some way to fix this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    \blindtext
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could use `\AddToHook{cmd/proof/after}{\leavevmode\color{blue}\ignorespaces}` but then you'd need to color "proof" separately

Comment: you could use the hyperref commands which save and restore spaces, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600142/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for this advice!

Comment: One way of implementing David's suggestion would be `\AddToHook{cmd/proof/after}{\leavevmode\color{blue}\ignorespaces}\usepackage{xpatch}\makeatletter\xpatchcmd{\proof}{#1\@addpunct {.}}{\textcolor{blue}{#1\@addpunct{.}}}{}{}\makeatother
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Ulrike Fischer's suggestion from the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{%
  \Hy@SaveLastskip
  \color{blue}%
  \Hy@RestoreLastskip
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    \blindtext
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for making this into a formal answer!